# Accessing dynamic column value in PostgreSQL Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am  writing trigger for record updation in  Postgresql using  plpgsql . In trigger, I am accessing  one value column value like below

```
    NEW.mobileno   -- This is usual way.
```

Now my requirement is , I will be having 'mobileno' text in  one variable  called dyn_columnname

Using this NEW and dyn_columnname , I should be access like  NEW.mobileno value.

How can I achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic sql:

```
execute _dyn_sql_string into _dyn_col_value using _dyn_col_name;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

It's usually better to avoid ending up with this situation to begin with, that being said, because the resulting query plans cannot be cached as efficiently as the plans from non-dynamic triggers.

If you're simply iterating through columns, consider approaching this by using dynamic sql, not to write a dynamic trigger function, but to write a dynamic function that creates or replaces a non-dynamic trigger function instead.

If you're using this because of some kind of business logic, consider revisitng your schema to aboid the situation entirely.